How do you get a Java NIO Server to accept connections from both Ipv4 and IPv6 on localhost?
I have a NIO-based server hosted locally on port 18888 that works fine with IPv4, i.e. I can connect a client successfully with either:

"localhost:18888"
"127.0.0.1:18888"

I was curious as to whether IPv6 would work, and tried the following:

"::1:18888"
"[::1]:18888"
"[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:18888"

All of these fail with the same exception:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:682)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:973)

Is there some reason why IPv6 might not be working in this situation when IPv4 is fine?
Note: It's a modern PC, Windows 11, JDK 21, to my knowledge IPv6 should be fully enabled, ping [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] works as expected etc.
EDIT: as suggested by larsks I tried netstat -aon and found a relevant line for IPv4 but apparently nothing for IPv6? Should there be a corresponding IPv6 entry?
 TCP    127.0.0.1:18888        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       54256


Connection refused means there is nothing listening at that port on that address.

It's possible that the NIO server is explicitly bound to IPv4. I'm not familiar with Windows; is there an equivalent to the Linux netstat command to show listening ports?

With some experimentation I discovered that binding the server socket to "localhost" only appears to listen to IPv4 local connections.
Binding the server socket to "::" appears to work for both IPv4 and IPv6 local access (i.e. clients can connect using both).
i.e. the relevant code on the server that solves my immediate problem is:
ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel= ServerSocketChannel.open();
InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("::",18888);
serverSocketChannel.bind(address);
....


risky - this binds on all ipv4 and ipv6 interfaces. not just localhost.

Yes, I'm aware of that. Fortunately not a problem in this particular application - though still curious if there is a way to bind to just localhost for IPv4 and IPv6?
